# How to connect Metamask wallet address to web3 on bsc testnet on React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web3js, binance

I am trying to connect my metamask wallet to the bsc testnet:

`const web3 = new Web3('https://data-seed-prebsc-1-s1.binance.org:8545');`

But when I try to get the accounts:

`const accounts_ = await web3.eth.getAccounts()`

web3.eth does not recognize the account on bsc testnet. Is there any configuration I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly **connect web3** by requesting for connection by:

```
const accounts = await web3.eth.requestAccounts();
```

Then save the address:

```
const address = accounts[0];
```

Now to **Add BNB network** to your metask account, to do that follow these steps:

1: Open Metamask settings

2: Then open the Networks tab in the settings.

3: Then click on add networks button to open the network form.

4: Fill all the fields for **Testnet BNB** network as following

- Network Name: **Smart Chain - Testnet**
- New RPC URL: **https://data-seed-prebsc-1-s1.binance.org:8545/**
- ChainID: **97**
- Symbol: **BNB**
- Block Explorer URL: **https://testnet.bscscan.com**

*Hurray!!* Now you have added the BNB network to your metamask.

Now refresh your page and click on the ***connect button*** on your page through which you call for the above functions for requesting address.